# Jquery image gallery .click failure

Tags: jquery, onclick, slidedown

My intent is to have `#photo_1` appear with a `.slideDown` when the image within the div is loaded. Subsequently, `#photo_2` (and on) will appear when (their corresponding thumbnail div) `#thumb_2` is clicked on.

Right now, `#imgwrap` which surrounds `#photo_1` and is a placeholder until `#photo_1` loads, sticks around when `#thumb_2` is clicked and `#photo_2` is supposed to appear. Then `#photo_2` appears beneath/stacked with `#imgwrap`.

I want `#imgwrap` to disappear, and the corresponding `#photo` to appear when any of the `#thumbs` other than the initial `#thumb_1` are clicked.

**Your help is much appreciated!**

```
<--!jquery image animation-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#photo_1").slideDown(500);
});

 $("#thumb_2").click(function () {
      $("#imgwrap").hide();
    });
    </script>

<!--HTML-->
  <div id="imgwrap">
        <div id="photo_1" style="opacity: 0.0;">
    <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="image 1" /></a>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div id="photo_2" style="display: none;">
    <img src="images/image_2.jpg" alt="image 2" /></a>
     </div>


<div id="thumb_1"><a href="#photo_1" onClick="switch_product_img('photo_1', 4);"><img src="images/image_thumb.jpg" alt="image thumbnail" /></a></div>

<div id="thumb_2"><a href="#photo_2" onClick="switch_product_img('photo_2', 4);"><img src="images/image_2_thumb.jpg" alt="image 2 thumbnail" /></a></div>

<!--JAVASCRIPT IMAGE ON-CLICK DISPLAY-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function switch_product_img(divName, totalImgs) 
        {
            for (var i=1; i<=totalImgs; i++) 
            {
                var showDivName = 'photo_' + i;
                var showObj = document.getElementById(showDivName);
                if (showDivName == divName)
                    showObj.style.display = 'block';
                else
                    showObj.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using standard javascript in jquery. You change picture func is too complicated.

Below script is very standard jquery. When you click on a "a" with class `thumbs` it will call the function  This script will hide all pictures with class `photos` and show the picture with id from the `href`.

```
<script>
$(function(){    //same as .load() but jquery style
  $("#dropimage").slideDown(500);
  $(".thumbs").click(function () {    // functions runs any time a <a href>  
                                      // with class thumbs` is clicked.

      var t = $(this);  // get the <a href> that was clicked.
       $('.photos').hide(); //hide all photos with class photo

      var href = t.attr('href'); //  get the href of the link clicked.
      $(href).show();    //show the photo u need. becauee the link and the
                         //id are the same.
    });

});
</script>

 <div id="photo_1" class="photos">
    <div id="dropimage" style="opacity: 0.0;">
<img src="images/image.jpg" alt="image 1" /></a>
 </div>
```

```
 <div class="photos" id="photo_2" style="display: none;">
    <img src="images/image_2.jpg" alt="image 2" /></a>
     </div>


<div id="thumb_1"><a class="thumbs" href="#photo_1"><img src="images/image_thumb.jpg" alt="image thumbnail" /></a></div>

<div id="thumb_2"><a class="thumbs"  href="#photo_2"><img src="images/image_2_thumb.jpg" alt="image 2 thumbnail" /></a></div>
```

`

Comment: Now just confused, code does not work and appears unrelated to the functions my previous code performs.


The entire site has photos and thumbs paired together in an image viewer. The js has a separate purpose from the jquery, it determines how the photos appear when their thumb is clicked on.

The jquery is for an appealing appearance of pre-loaded images. The intent is to have a placeholder shape when the users first loads the page. The placeholder shape is then replaced with the first photo. Cue the javascript which swaps the corresponding photo when its thumbnail is clicked.

Comment: I added back your slidedown. But the rest will work as expected. And added comments for you in the code